# How to strip invalid characters from a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, visual-studio, windows-ce

I am trying to modify a program on Windows CE 5.0 device that scans barcode for dates..
What is the best way to strip invalid string from the date format

example:

```
2014/03/12 --> 20140312
2014.03.12 --> 20140312
2014-03-12 --> 20140312
```

What I want is to automatically remove those strings(/,-,.)

Thanks!

Comment: Side note: make sure there are no cases like 20-12-2011...

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
Regex.Replace("2014/03/12", "[^0-9]", string.Empty)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method:

```
string s = "2014/03/12";
s = s.Replace('/').Replace('.').Replace('-');
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more info.

Note: this approach is fine for a limited number of characters, for more complex string manipulation you will want to use `Regex`

Comment: This solution will require you to string Replace calls for every character other than 0-9 in order to match the same functionality provided by the Regex solution.

Comment: @MikeParkhill OP asked to remove 3 characters from a string. Also `string.Replace` can be faster then `Regex.Replace` [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debuggingtoolbox/archive/2008/04/02/comparing-regex-replace-string-replace-and-stringbuilder-replace-which-has-better-performance.aspx)

Comment: True enough. I guess I didn't read the post closely enough. In such a specific case the string.Replaces will probably be faster (esp. since only of them is likely to find a match causing extra memory usage and gc).

Comment: @MikeParkhill any chance of removing the -1 then :P